# High Frequency Market Making When Short Selling Is Prohibited

Tags: high-frequency, market-making

I am seeking insights on high-frequency market making strategies in markets where short selling is prohibited. While browsing through research papers and [quant.stackexchange.com](https://quant.stackexchange.com), there's frequent mention of double-sided bid and ask quotes. However, in markets where short selling is not allowed, I guess this aspect becomes irrelevant. Are there any studies or resources addressing this specific challenge? Alternatively, how can existing high-frequency trading market making literature be adapted to accommodate the absence of short selling mechanisms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/current_issues/ci18-5.pdf